# Magento 2 - All products attributes updated after update from collection

Tags: magento2, collection, products, magento-2.2.5, attribute-value

I have got collection in `$collecction` from `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` with some certain conditions

I am updating a custom attribute `viewed_count` in `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach($collection as $k=>$_product){
    echo $_product->getSku()." ";
    $viewCount = $this->getViewedCount($_product->getId());
    $_product->getResource()->saveAttribute($_product, "viewed_count");
    $_product->setViewedCount($viewCount);
    $_product->save();
}
```

After this it is successfully updating product viewed count in `viewed_count` attribute.

**But the issue is:** After this code is executed, all other attributes got updated and set to some default values. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference Link](https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2017/10/13/how-to-update-product-specific-attribute-value-in-magento2/)

`updateAttributes` of class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action`. Method can update multiple products and attribute values, but if you want to update just one product with one attribute value you can do it like this:

`$this->action->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], ['attribute_code' => $newValue], $storeId);`

Comment: `$this->action` is the object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action`?

Comment: yes bro.........

Comment: Thanks Rk Rathod I will try this. Will let you know when it resolved :)

Comment: ok buddy....... :)

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: most welcome bro happy coding :)